# Python pandas replace string

Tags: python, pandas

Given this data frame...:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','D','D'], 
                   'COL2': [11032, 1960, 11400, 11355, 8, 7], 
                   'year': ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']})
DF

   COL1 COL2    year
0   A   11032   2016
1   B   1960    2017
2   C   11400   2018
3   D   11355   2019
4   D   8       2020
5   D   7       2021
```

If the following conditions are met:

> 1. COL1 = 'D'
> 2. year = '2021' (please treat it as a string)

Then change the value in `COL2` to `100`.

Alternatively, what if year is treated as an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical use case of [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label).  When selecting multiple criteria for the row selection, an example of a `cond 1 and (cond 2 or cond 3)` pattern would be `df.loc[(condition 1) & ((condition 2) | (condition 3), 'selected columns']`.

```
DF.loc[(DF.COL1 == 'D') & (DF.year == '2021'), 'COL2'] = 100
```

If the year were an integer, you could simply amend it as follows to capture both integers and strings:

```
DF.loc[(DF.COL1 == 'D') & (DF.year.astype(int) == 2021), 'COL2'] = 100
```

Comment: What if I wanted to use a column name in place of 'D' and 2021 to iterate through two columns containing values including 'D' and 2021 and change the corresponding value per row in 'COL2'?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Can you post a new question with sample data and desired result?

Comment: Sure; posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029505/python-pandas-conditional-replace-string-based-on-column-values