# Python pandas conditional replace string based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

Given these data frames...:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','D','D'], 
                   'COL2': [11032, 1960, 11400, 11355, 8, 7], 
                   'year': ['2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']})
DF

   COL1 COL2    year
0   A   11032   2016
1   B   1960    2017
2   C   11400   2018
3   D   11355   2019
4   D   8       2020
5   D   7       2021

DF2 = pd.DataFrame({'ColX': ['D'], 'ColY':['2021'], 'ColZ':[100]
DF2
        ColX   ColY    ColZ
   0     D      2021   100
```

If the following conditions are met:

COL1 = ColX from DF2

year = ColY from DF2

Then change the value in COL2 to ColZ from DF2.

Comment: What if there were multiple `ColZ` values for the same matching pairs of `ColX` and `ColY`?

Comment: There will not be, I promise.

Comment: DF2['ColY'] should be ['2021'] correct? It says 2012, but 2021 in the output.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'll fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you want to `update` `DF` with data from `DF2`.

Assuming that all values in `DF2` are unique for a given pair of values in `ColX` and `ColY`:

```
DF = DF.merge(DF2.set_index(['ColX', 'ColY'])[['ColZ']], 
              how='left', 
              left_on=['COL1', 'year'], 
              right_index=True)
DF.COL2.update(DF.ColZ)
del DF['ColZ']

>>> DF
  COL1   COL2  year
0    A  11032  2016
1    B   1960  2017
2    C  11400  2018
3    D  11355  2019
4    D      8  2020
5    D    100  2021
```

I merge a temporary dataframe (`DF2.set_index(['ColX', 'ColY'])[['ColZ']]`) into DF, which adds all the values from ColZ where its index (`ColX` and `ColY`) match the values from `COL1` and `year` in `DF`.  All non-matching values are filled with `NA`.

I then use `update` to overwrite the values in `DF.COL2` from the non-null values in DF.ColZ.

I then delete DF['ColZ'] to clean-up.

If `ColZ` matches an existing column name in `DF`, then you would need to make some adjustments.

An alternative solution is as follows:

```
DF = DF.set_index(['COL1', 'year']).update(DF2.set_index(['ColX', 'ColY']))
DF.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The output is identical to that above.

Comment: As the song goes:Thank you...thank you...thank God for you the wind beneath my wings...

Comment: One more thing (hopefully): What if I wanted to add the condition: if less than all conditions (2) are met (found), replace the current value with 'n/a'?

Comment: With the first method above, I believe DF.ColZ will give you what you want (i.e. don't delete it).  It is all matching values from DF2 given your two conditions, with n/a for unmatched values.